# Pie chart with legend position south

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, legend, charts, pgf-pie

I tried the legend to the south code from this question (see code below): [Pie chart with joined legend position](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503651/pie-chart-with-joined-legend-position/631212#631212)

but it unfortunately does not work.

If i change yshift to a fixed value it work. BUT only when i compile it in overleaf - if I compile it with textstudio it does not.

Can someone tell me whats the problem with overleaf vs. my local latex distribution?

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
legend to the south/.code={
\coordinate[xshift=-1.5cm,
yshift=(\value{pgfpie@sliceLength}*0.5+1)*0.5cm-4em] (legendpos) at
(current bounding box.south);},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
every path/.style={draw=white, very thick}
]
\pie[square, 
scale font,
color = {blue!10, blue!20, blue!40}, 
sum=auto, text=legend, 
after number = {\%}, 
style={legend to the south}
]{58/Unidentifiable ML,25/MOP only,11/SMO only,6/MOP \& SMP} 
\end {tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Comment (%) the line: 'style={legend to the south}' or see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503651/pie-chart-with-joined-legend-position?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro: The legend to the south part is what i want to achieve. The example you reference is the one i try to implement but is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The solution from [Pie chart with joined legend position](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503651/pie-chart-with-joined-legend-position/631212#631212) is prior to pgf-pie v0.4 in which they moved the definitions from .cls to .tex.

What I did was to download the [pgf-pie v0.3 .cls file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pgf-tikz/pgf-pie/0.3/tex/latex/pgf-pie/pgf-pie.sty) as pgf-pie3.cls and import it locally. Then I used fixed positions for `xshift` and `yshift`:

```
    \tikzset{
    legend to the south/.code={{
    \coordinate[xshift=-1.5cm, yshift=2mm] (legendpos) at
    (current bounding box.south);}},
    }
```